# Django-rest-framework api add SessionAuthentication as optional

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

Hi i'm currently have my api that use this [simple-JWT](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) package for jwt token authentication, it worked great. But now when i try to call the api from the django website app using Ajax in which is from a page user already logged in but it still required me to use the jwt access_token.

My ajax call from the page user already logged in:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/api/add_favorite/" + property_id + "/",
       beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {{ refresh_token }}');
       },
       success: function (data) {
       if (data.code == 200) {
              alert('added to favorite');
              replace_part_1 = '<a id="mylink2" href="#" value="' + property_id +'"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Remove from favorite"></i></a>'
              $("a[value='" + property_id + "']").replaceWith(replace_part_1);
             }
       }
});
```

Now i don't want to set the header with authorization since in the page user already logged in so the session is already set.

So i tried to add Django Session authentication to the the api like so:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, JWTAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def add_favorite(request, property_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            favorite_property = Property.objects.get(pk=property_id)
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                login_user = request.user
                if not login_user.properties.filter(pk=property_id).exists():
                    login_user.properties.add(favorite_property)

                    return JsonResponse({'code':'200','data': favorite_property.id}, status=200)
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'code':'404','errors': "Property already exists in favorite"}, status=404)

        except Property.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'code':'404','errors': "Property not found"}, status=404)
```

My Ajax after removed the header :

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/api/add_favorite/" + property_id + "/",
       },
       success: function (data) {
       if (data.code == 200) {
              alert('added to favorite');
              replace_part_1 = '<a id="mylink2" href="#" value="' + property_id +'"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Remove from favorite"></i></a>'
              $("a[value='" + property_id + "']").replaceWith(replace_part_1);
             }
       }
});
```

and i removed the set header from the Ajax call now i get 403 return code :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden)

My settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    # 'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

I don't know why the session authentication doesn't work since the Ajax call is from the page user already logged in.

Thank for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're adding `Authentication` header on your ajax requests, Django automatically use `TokenAuthentication` if `Authentication` exists on the request header. Remove it to use SessionAuthentication.

There might be a problem when you're switch to use SessionAuthentication is that Django will reject your `unsafe` requests if there is no `CSRF` token, more detail [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication)

Comment: I had edited my question with the ajax when i sent and get the error, the Authentication part on header already removed

Comment: Is there any other message from server, you could use Chrome Dev Tools -> open Network tab to see the response message. I think that it will be something related to CSRF, but yeah, try that and update your question with the response message

Comment: you are right, it was missing csrf i totally forgot about that. i changed my ajax set header to xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{csrf_token}}'); and it worked now thank you